# How to bind lat/long values to knockout viewmodel method?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to use knockout to build an app to display some location details and markers on a google map
I have the google map being displayed based on user location by checking if 'navigator.geolocation' is true. If true, I am calling the 'navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()' method to display the map centered at the lat long retrieved by 'position.coords.latitude'.

```
var fooBarApp = (function(){
 ...
 initMap: function() {
  ...
  }

  return {
        lat: lat,
        long: long
   }
})();
```

After the coordinates are retrieved and the map is displayed, I want to display the map markers & make an ajax call  to another api and display the results- all of which I am handling inside my viewModel. So here is what my viewModel looks like:

```
var viewModel = new function() {

  self.fetchList = function() {
  //ajax call to api using fooBarApp.lat & fooBarApp.long
  }

  self.fetchList() // method call to display results on page load
}
```

Currently on page load, the fetchList ajax call takes place with undefined lat,long values - cause the values aren't retrieved by the time the ajax call is triggered. When the fetchList is called on click of a DOM element, the ajax call fires successfully. How should I restructure my code such that the fetchList is called on page load, only after the coordinates are retrieved? Also, is moving the initMap logic inside viewModel and making the lat long observables a good idea?

Comment: place `ko.applyBindings(viewModel)` after you make sure your document is ready and coordinates are retrieved

Comment: Not sure how/where to check when the coordinates are retrieved..

Comment: EDIT: I placed the applyBinding and ajax call  after map idle and that seems to work. Thanks!

`google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                viewModel.fetchList();
            });`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to make the ajax call and with that response, place the markers? You should call the method to place the markers in the callback of the ajax call.

Comment: In order to make the ajax call, I need the lat/long values, which are coming as undefined on initial page load. If the same ajax call is being fired on a click event, the lat/long values are being retrieved fine. I need to make the ajax call after the values have been fetched and not sure how to handle that.